# jsTree: Expand node by name

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, jstree

I have a jQuery jsTree populated from the server via an ajax call. How i can expand node, by node name, not id? e.g. sample node:

[{"attributes":[],"data":{"title":"mynode1","id":"1a051101-c3fa-48f2-b2e1-c60d1b67ea22"},"children":[{"attributes":[],"data":{"title":"mynode2","id":"26d6cff1-3c7f-4a2f-bf5a-422e08127b43"

how i can expand node, if a know only his name ("mynode1")?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically you would not want to open a node by the title, but it can be done. If the same title is found more than once, then both will open. Replace the ".jstree" selector with one that is unique to your tree.

```
var open_node_name="mynode1";
$(".jstree").find("a").each( function(index){
    if($(this).text().trim()==open_node_name){
        $.jstree._reference(".jstree").open_node($(this),function(){;},true);
    }
});
```